# How to browse a hsql memory database with Eclipse Datasource Explorer?

Tags: database, eclipse, hsqldb, in-memory-database

I want to connect an in-memory database with eclipse database explorer, but it seems only support traditional hsql database? Is there any way to create a in-memory database instance in eclipse database explorer?

Comment: what happens when you use `jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test` as the connection URL?

Comment: it doesn't really connect to the memory database, I just use squirrel gui client can connect to this database, It has one database type is HSQLDB-IN Memory. but I can't find it in Eclipse DTP plugin.So I think this is the reason I can't connect.